# Sumar numeros en cadena de una lista

Tags: python

recién estoy empezando en el mundo de Python y estoy atascado con un ejercicio hace un par de días. Resulta que tengo una lista con x cantidad de números, lo que tengo desmembrar en subcadenas. Ej. 4 5 6 2. Tendría que hacer una lista que contenga "4,45,456,4562,5,56,562,6,62,2".

Comment: 1) Para separar la cadena en partes `split` https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp; para convertir cada cadena en un numero 2) Para convertir las cadenas en numero y poderlas usar von el operador de suma aritmetica https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-string-to-int/ para iterar cada elemento de la cadena https://j2logo.com/bucle-for-en-python/ usa cada una de estas tres cosas en el orden correcto

Answer (score 0):

No sé si tu pregunta que fue borrada hace un rato, que es esta:

En este ejercicio el usuario debe ingresar un numero, el programa debe separar los caracteres del numero
y hacer una lista sumando todos las combinaciones posibles.
Ej: 4564 -
(4, 45,456,4564,5,56,564,6,64).

La pregunta estaba mejor planteada y con lo que llevaba trabajado. De todas formas aquí tienes respuesta para las 2.

`from itertools import combinations` nos genera las combinaciones

```
from itertools import combinations

num = '4564'
lista_de_posibilidades = []
lista_de_sumas = []
for i in range(1, len(num)+1):
    c = combinations(num, i)
    for x in c:
        lista_de_posibilidades.append(x)
print(lista_de_posibilidades)
```

Así tienes la lista de posibilidades. Podría ser que quisieras sumar esos números.

Lo primero es que tienes un `string` que para sumarlo habría que pasar cada dígito a `ìnt`, que sería la función `map(int, x)`

El código completo podría ser:

```
num = '4564'
lista_de_posibilidades = []
lista_de_sumas = []
for i in range(1, len(num)+1):
    c = combinations(num, i)
    for x in c:
        lista_de_posibilidades.append(x)
        lista_de_sumas.append(sum(map(int, x)))

print(lista_de_posibilidades)
#   Dado que 6 + 4 = 4 + 6 un set() elimina los duplicados
#   La lista se puede ordenar con sorted()
lista_de_sumas = sorted(set(lista_de_sumas))
print(lista_de_sumas)
```